# It rains a lot in winter. vs There is a lot of rain in winter

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference

When I translate these sentences in my native language I don't feel any difference. Could you tell me these differences if they are?

> It rains a lot in winter.

vs

> There is a lot of rain in winter.

Do you use both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning, and both are idiomatic.

From the perspective of style, which is of course opinion rather than objective, I prefer "It rains," both because it is slightly more concise and also because "there is" as a dummy subject is overused. But this does not affect the answer to your question, which is whether the two forms have any difference in meaning. No, they do not.